# Posting JSON from ajax to Struts2 Action

Tags: java, ajax, json, eclipse, struts2

Hey I am trying to post JSON from Ajax to Struts2 action class method. Little more info: I am running client on WAMP server and Struts2 on Eclipse Tomcat.

My client side code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dataObj = {
"data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Chris"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Kate"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Blade"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Zack"
}]
};

var data1 = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8080/Core/add",type: "post", data:  data1, dataType: 'json',      contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",async: true,success:function(result){
  $("#div1").html(result);
}});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Java application stuff:

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd">



<struts>

       <package name="addMenu" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

      <action name="registrate" class="com.coreRestaurant.menu.MenuAction">
          <result type="json" >
          <param name="root">json</param>
          </result>
      </action>

      <action name="read" class="com.coreRestaurant.menu.MenuAction" method="readMenuById">
          <result type="json" >
          <param name="root">json</param>
          </result>
      </action>

      <action name="add" class="com.coreRestaurant.menu.MenuAction" method="addMenu">
         <result type="json" >
         <param name="root">data</param>
         </result>
      </action>

   </package>

</struts>
```

And this is my java code (`MenuAction.java`):

```
    package com.coreRestaurant.menu;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

    public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Menu>, Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Menu menu = new Menu();

    private String json;

    private List<Menu> data = new ArrayList<Menu>();



    public String execute(){
        MenuService menuService = new MenuService();
        setJson(new Gson().toJson(menuService.getMenuNames()));
        if(menuService.isDatabaseConnectionDown()==false){
            return SUCCESS;
        }else{
            setJson(new Gson().toJson("Failed to connect to Database"));
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    public String readMenuById(){
        MenuService menuService = new MenuService();
        setJson(new Gson().toJson(menuService.getSpecificalMenuNameById(menu.getId())));
        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public String addMenu(){
        MenuService menuService = new MenuService();
        System.out.println(data);
        for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(data.get(i));
        }
        menu.setName("Postitus");
        menuService.addMenu(menu);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }


    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }


    @Override
    public Menu getModel() {
        return menu;
    }

    public List<Menu> getData() {
        System.out.println("Getter Call");
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Menu> data) {
        System.out.println("Setter Call Flow");
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And the `Menu.java` itself:

```
package com.coreRestaurant.menu;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Menu implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

All the time when I run my client side code, I can see the following input only from Eclipse console:

```
[]
Getter Call
```

Why is it empty? I expect to have that JSON array from client side but no success.

Comment: Stop using modeldriven. You need to include `JSONInterceptor` into your stack.

Comment: Do you want Gson to get your array?

Comment: I want "data" variable to contain information that comes from client side. I would use gson to for other purposes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send JSON data via Ajax you need to parse it by the Struts2 `json` interceptor. It will also populate your data property of the action object, but you should remove `ModelDriven` fom the action class. Unless you define a property to populate a list data from the json interceptor on the model you can't use model driven with json. To add `json` interceptor to the action config, you can override its interceptors.

```
<action name="add" class="com.coreRestaurant.menu.MenuAction" method="addMenu">
  <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
  <result type="json" >
    <param name="root">data</param>
  </result>
</action>
```