# Post json to struts 2 action

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I need to post a simple json object to a Struts 2 action, could you tell me what I miss with this:

the Java object to save:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
@Column(name = "libelle_fr")
private String libelleFr;
@Column(name = "libelle_nl")
private String libelleNl;
```

I use alpine.js but it's a detail, the script called to send the request is this one:

```
<script>
    function postForm() {
        return {
            indicateurDictionnaireForm: {
                libelleFr: '',
                libelleNl: '',
                code: ''
            },
            message: '',

            submitData() {
                this.message = ''

                fetch('<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.ce.save.action', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    dataType:"json",
                    body: JSON.stringify(this.indicateurDictionnaireForm)
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.message = 'Form sucessfully submitted!'
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        this.message = 'Ooops! Something went wrong!'
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

the json sent to the action is:

```
{
"libelleFr":"fr",
"libelleNl":"nl",
"code":"sample"
}
```

from my action file there is my method called from the front:

```
private IndicateurDictionnaire indicateurDictionnaireForm;

// Action to save an indicateurDictionnaireto database
@Action(value = "mesures.indicateurs.ce.save", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"root", "indicateurDictionnaireForm"}),
            @Result(name = "input", type = "tiles", params = {"root", "indicateurDictionnaireForm"}, location = "viewMesureCoutUnitaire")})
    public String save(IndicateurDictionnaire indicateurDictionnaire, String libelleFr, String libelleNl, String code) {
        dictionnaireIndicateurBo.saveIndicateurDictionnaire(indicateurDictionnaire);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

According the struts2 json pluggin, the json should be mapped to my object if it's properly formatted but the fields are empty if I look in debug.

Do you know how I can proceed to at least see the json request in my action method?

Comment: The Struts 2 should *not* accept json values from the request, unless this feature is enabled even via the plugin. You should read the corresponding documentation page to learn how to do it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16752302/573032) answer has a similar problem and you should read it before if you need a problem solved with the solution.

Comment: Hi @RomanC and thanks for your repply. The struts 2 pluggin was already added. I looked the documentation but I don't see the example with anotations (like my action class in the op). Also can you confirm if the json pluggin is in the projet, can I just send the json data with the same structure than the dto and the pluggin will auto populate the dto fields?

Comment: @RomanC I did with success the second option that you described without the interceptor and it works but if I understand the first option with the plug-in is faster

Comment: The plugin is supported from the Struts 2 framework, so you don't need to write your own serializer and deserializer.

Comment: thanks @RomanC. ,Tto send the form detail to the DTO called "indicateurDictionnaireForm" in my op, Does the request is correct? I have a doubt about the structure of the JSON, Do I need to wrap with indicateurDictionnaireForm? I tried like that but same prob the dto is not populated:
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
async: true,
url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/mesures.indicateurs.ce.save.action",
data: {"indicateurDictionnaireForm": JSON.stringify(this.indicateurDictionnaireForm)},
success: function (data) {
},
error: function (request, error) {
}
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods that are mapped to the actions not use any parameters in the method signature. So you need to remove those parameters and add `json` interceptor to the action config.

This field is used as [`root` object](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/#root-object) by the json interceptor and should not be `null`.

```
IndicateurDictionnaire indicateurDictionnaire;
// getter and setter should be added

@Action(value = "mesures.indicateurs.ce.save", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"root", "indicateurDictionnaire"})
}, interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value = "json", params = {"root", "indicateurDictionnaire"}))
public String save() {       
  dictionnaireIndicateurBo.saveIndicateurDictionnaire(indicateurDictionnaire);
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works !! I had another issue, my action class implemented the model driven but I found in another answer from you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493800/posting-json-from-ajax-to-struts2-action/26757003#26757003 that it cant work so I removed the modelDriven and it works now. Many thanks for your help